# Adding custom code to a report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report

I want to custom code to a report.
For example, I have a text box, txtABC on the report.
I want to assign it a value from variable, when report runs.

How to do it.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

The link to the MS article on how to do this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx).